# Streaming data transfer using WCF

Tags: wcf

While transferring large file using streamed request in WCF, how can I be assured that the data has been received at Client end. I mean how can i ensure reliable transfer of data and get an acknowlegement.

Answer (score 0):

I am not siure that i get you right. But if i do, then:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=721

if not please be more specific when and what kind of resposne from service you are expecting

Comment: Let me explain in detail about my requirement:I need to transfer data to a client through WCF services. Data can be of 1MB to 1GB size to be transferred.
So, what can I do, I can pull Data from the database and provided to the client through WCF service.Client can then add it in its local database. How can I manage transferring large data? I want to be able to resume the process if it fails in the middle of the transfer. How can I know if the Client local database has been updated or not.Should I be using a WCF streaming?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure that streaming would be good option for you, because it has limitation on the binding and also your requirement is to continue transferring of the data, so it would be better to send data in chunks.

Comment: Also you can copy the required beforehand or lock it, in order to make sure that during transfer it would be unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create a check-sum of the data before sending it and then after you received data you could calculate again the check-sum and verify that it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

What we do is we calculate an MD5 hash on the byte array before we send it, then send that text value with the byte package to the host, which then calculates another MD5 hash (again, based on the bytes) and does a comparison between the expected MD5 hash (sent by the client) and the one freshly calculated on the host. If they're not the same, you know you didn't get the complete file, forcing you to send that error back in the response.

Here's an example of the little function we use to calc the hash:

```
Protected Function GetMD5HashFromBuffer(ByVal oBuffer As Byte()) As String
  Dim md5 As System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 = New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
  Dim retVal() As Byte = md5.ComputeHash(oBuffer)
  'fileSize = file.Length
  'file.Close()
  Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  Do While (i < retVal.Length)
    sb.Append(retVal(i).ToString("x2"))
    i = (i + 1)
  Loop
  Return sb.ToString
End Function
```